# How to sort/order a model's fields?

Tags: php, laravel

I do `$users = User::all();` This gives me a collection of User objects, where each object has fields something like:

```
[   
    {
      "id":10,
      "age":10,
      "name":"John",
      "bank_no":5454

   },
   {
      "id":20,
      "age":10,
      "name":"Jane",
      "bank_no":457

   }
]
```

I want each User objects keys to be ordered alphabetically,

For ex:

```
[   
   {
      "age":10,
      "bank_no":5454      
      "id":10,
      "name":"John"

   },
   {
      "age":10,
      "bank_no":457      
      "id":20,
      "name":"Jane"

   }
]
```

Now I know that this order comes the order in which the fields are defined in the migration file. But, changing the migration is not an option for me.

How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Can you share a reproducable example of your problem? How **exactly** do you print these models?

Comment: @NicoHaase when I return the JSON response as this collection this is the order it takes (I assume default from the order they were defined in the migrations file). I want to avoid sorting them at the frontend as it's a collection and not just one single object.

Comment: Just to be sure: you waant the keys in the inner object to be ordered? Is your frontend not capable of handling unordered objects?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes, that is correct. My implementation makes it more difficult to do this at the front-end. because this particular front-end takes multiple types of Models for the same view. hence I felt it's best for the server to send the desired o/p. The front end will then process it as it would process any other collection.

Comment: You can use orderBy in your query like this: `$users = User::orderBy('age', 'DESC')->get();` this will give you dessending order by age.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by keys you can to do this :

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
    ksort($key); 
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Does this sort the listing of fields within a model, or does this sort all models by name?

Comment: Oh, thanks, i read again his problem, he want sort key, not all models by name. I re-edit my responses.

Comment: @GaryHoubre Hi Gary, your solution is not helpful in this case. I want to sort each object's keys and not the whole collection itself

Comment: Hi, I feel your answer is incomplete,  what should be the logic inside the `macro` function?

Answer (score 0):

here try [this](https://tehplayground.com/fVNW4rnJtAtIc879), I'm not sure if this going to be the efficient solutions for a very long list of users but it should work regardless.

```
$json = '[   
    {
      "id":10,
      "age":10,
      "name":"John",
      "bank_no":5454

   },
   {
      "id":20,
      "age":10,
      "name":"Jane",
      "bank_no":457

   }
]';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$res = [];
foreach($arr as $arrObj){
    ksort($arrObj);
    $res[] = $arrObj; 
}

print_r($res);
```

**Laravel sort function on collection** see documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortkeys)

```
$collection = collect([
    'id' => 22345,
    'first' => 'John',
    'last' => 'Doe',
]);

$sorted = $collection->sortKeys();

$sorted->all();
```

Comment: I originally have a Collection and not a JSON string also Is there any way to do this without looping over all the objects again?